# PostgreSQL UUID and H2 compatibility

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I have a service written in Spring Boot that uses PostgreSQL with driver 42.3.5. Previously it was on Oracle and we are migrating to PostgreSQL.
For my entities, I have the PK as UUID so in order to have it properly in both the DB and in my Entities classes, I added the annotation `@Type(type = "pg-uuid")`

Everything works fine, until some integration tests that use an in-memory H2 database. For the tests, the Spring Context can not start because `pg-uuid` is not recognized in H2. If I make the `@Type(type = 'uuid-char')` for the ID column, I get an error on PostgreSQL where it things that the column should be VARCHAR and NOT UUID.

Is there a way to have it work with both H2 and PostgreSQL properly? I know that one solution would be to have the column as VARCHAR instead of UUID in the database, but I would prefer to use it as a proper UUID.

Comment: https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Comment: Both H2 and PostgreSQL have native `UUID` data type, new versions of Hibernate should be able to use it automatically with default settings.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Not an option for me. This is an enterprise application where there are firewall rules and other restrictions and the build environment does not have access to the testing DB and I can't deploy a docker image. I know it may sound crazy, but it is what it is and I don't have the power to change this across the whole company.